# Show hidden div once responsive table gets scrollable in small device

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

A project in which I am working has too many tables in it. I am finished with them and made them responsive. 
Tables take vertical scroll if it does not fit in any device.
All tables are of different widths.

For example,

- Table A takes vertical scroll from a device smaller than 768px
- Table B takes vertical scroll from a device smaller than 667px
- Table C takes vertical scroll from a device smaller than 414px
- and many more....

Now I want to show one note informing about scrollable table only when it takes a scroll.
I have to manually do this by applying different class and media queries to all tables. And it will be too time-consuming as I have too many tables.

**Is there any CSS trick or script that displays that note once table gets scrollable?**

See below snippet. Here `<p>` takes `display:block` in device 736px and lower, as the table is scrollable there.

```css
p{
font-family:arial;
display:none;
}

table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

td, th {
    border: 1px solid #ababab;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #dddddd;
}

.scrollable {
    overflow-x: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 736px)
{
p{
display:block;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollable">
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
    <td>Laughing Bacchus Winecellars</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
    <td>Yoshi Tannamuri</td>
    <td>Canada</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
    <td>Magazzini Alimentari Riuniti</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
    <td>Giovanni Rovelli</td>
    <td>Italy</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
<p>Note: Scroll above table to see more content.</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compare the widths of the `.scrollable` element and the `table`. If there is a scroll - the table should be wider than its container:

```
var $containers = $('.scrollable');

$containers.each(function() { // in case there are multiple scrollable tables on the page
    var $container = $(this);
    var $table = $container.find('table');

    if ( $container.width() < $table.width() ) {
        $container.addClass('show-notice');
    }
});
```

CSS update per your example:

```
.scrollable.show-notice p { display: block; }
```

Comment: please explain this with example

Comment: Edited - more detailed example.

Comment: Error: "message": "Uncaught ReferenceError: $container is not defined",
  "filename": "https://stacksnippets.net/js",
  "lineno": 114,
  "colno": 14
}

Comment: Edited - $table variable declaration moved inside the $.each

Comment: Thanks. It worked :) you converted my work which would take 3-4 days into 10 minutes